# How to use compress Javascirpt file (.gz) in visual studio MVC4 webportal

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, compression

I have on the web portal in that I had applied bundling and It is working fine. Now, I want to apply compression in the JS file. So, that I have manually compress js file using gunzip. After that, I have copied all the JS files in my publish folder. Now I am not getting any errors in the browser console. But publish website not working.

In IIS(v.10) static compression enabled. I do not want to happy dynamic compression due to which will use CPU.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Still, I haven't found any solution. Please guide me

Comment: I am looking for this solution from last 2 months. Still, I haven't found anything. Can you please help me